# Trackpad Freezes often

Tags: 11.10, freeze, trackpad

I have newly installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my system and as soon as I start my system the trackpad freezes and I have to restart the system once again and there after every few minutes this keeps happening.Any solution for this problem ??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried the command (in terminal window, <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-T</kbd> )

`synclient TouchpadOff=0`

It will not solve the problem, but maybe unfreeze he touchpad for the moment.

Another fix that has been reported is to uncheck the "Disable touchpad while typing" in the system settings, mouse and touchpad.

Hopefully all the filed bug reports will lead to a permanent solution, but for now you can try the above suggestions.

Comment: I had same problem,DISABLE TOUCHPAD WHILE TYPING worked for me, Thanks a bunch

Comment: Typed in the command and my touchpad worked again instantly. I have also unchecked the option in settings but can't say whether it helps or not yet. It's not frozen yet, which is good ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm having this problem too, but after trying different solutions, I founded that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (the simple text copy command), no matter where I am, my touchpad goes off and pressing again <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> give me back my touchpad ...

Anyway I think is just a shortcut from Compiz, because is the only change I have made recently...But I didn't found it yet !

I hope this helps someone...

PS: Always the commands

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

had worked for me !

Comment: I first used `lsmod` to list. I then had to do the above for `hid_multitouch`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like recent interactions from other projects has caused this bug to become more visible.  see [bug:868400](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/868400).

Workaround from the bug:

1. open terminal window, `<Ctrl-Alt-T>`
2. type: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false`
3. close your session with: `gnome-session-quit`
4. After logging in again - should be back to working.

Also, plugging in a USB mouse worked for me before I tried the workaround.